# Should I upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 with 2 gb ram?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I have:-

1. Intel core2duo E7500 2.93GHz dual core processor
2. 2 Gb DDR2 ram
3. Intel 945G graphics. (No graphics card)
4. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit working fine.
   Should I upgrade to 18.04?

Comment: In any way I'll recommend to buy more RAM. 2 Gb is not enough. Check your motherboard slot configuration and order 4-8 Gb for it. AliExpress may be a solution to get lower costs.

Comment: From the Ubuntu desktop system requirements link comment above, you would appear to need 4 GB RAM to run 18.04 successfully     :                                      
 Bionic Beaver (18.04 64-bit)
2 GHz dual core processor or better
4 GB system memory (since 18.04.2)

Comment: I tested Ubuntu *flavors* using devices (pentium M/pentium 4 & more) with 1GB of RAM up to the disco/19.04 cycle, though of course I'd do things differently on a device with that much ram (little multitasking). I test using c2d for releases up to the current *hirsute* though most have >2GB RAM (exception is thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb ram, i915)) but I'd opt for a lighter flavor than GNOME myself. 16.04 reaches EOL in April-2021; a 18.04 flavor may have parts that reach EOL then too, but other parts still get updated so I'd go 18.04 *flavor* (like I have on the sl510).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hardware is getting a little long in the tooth -- <3 GHz, 2 GB RAM, and Intel graphics is barely capable of running one of the lightweight versions of Ubuntu, like Budgie, Mate, or Xubuntu.  I'd recommend trying one of those flavors on a Live Session with some of the applications you usually use (you can often browse to them on your existing install and run them from your hard disk while booted from a USB drive).

If the overall performance is acceptable, it should be slightly better from an installed copy -- your hard disk is usually going to be faster than a USB drive on an older machine like that.

Options that might help out, and are cheaper than a whole new system (assuming this is a desktop machine with socketed CPU): A Core2Quad processor with higher clock speed will significantly improve performance, and replacing your RAM (probably 2x 1GB modules) with 2x 2GB or 2x 4GB (the latter may be outside your motherboard's supported total, however) will make a big difference in the way your computer runs.

Comment: It depends what he uses system for and how heavy.  Do know that Lubuntu can run with half his specs, if not pushed.

Comment: Was Lubuntu still offered in 18.04?  I thought Canonical had dropped that flavor.

Comment: Running Lubuntu 18.04 on an old P4(last upgrade is known).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe i`ll just wait to get a new pc (as this motherboard is not gonna support the graphics card and I will just get DDR4 rams for new pc). But this pc is not so bad. I usually browse internet and watch youtube videos on this pc. Once google chrome is loaded on the ram, it opens all websites as fast as thunder. I just need to load the programs once on the ram and they run like charm then.

Comment: Yep, that's the beauty of Linux.  You might look at other distros, too -- AntiX is designed for low-spec machines; I used to run it on a PII 266 with less than 1 GB RAM (though this was several years ago).  Still has a reasonably up to date kernel, and it's supported, too.